# ATP to disassembly of nucleotide ratio

Tags: human-biology, molecular-genetics, gene-expression

DNA Helicase, the enzyme that is responsible for tearing apart the strands before DNA replication, requires ATP to rip apart nucleotides. I have asked this question to several professors and they couldn't give me a clear answer. My question: What is the ATP:nucleotide bond breakage ratio? In other words, how many nucleotide  bonds can be broken from a single ATP through helicase.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/5/1443.full.pdf) should interest you, though it likely varies between different helicases.

Comment: I think requirement of ATP also depends on the arrangement of oligonucleotide that mean bound between A and T(u) or G and C, and it could be calculate but how I cann't say yet.

Comment: All helicase is doing is opening up the DNA double helix by disrupting the hydrogen bonds between the nucleotides. The bond in hydrogen bonds is a misnomer as it is a van der Waals interaction and not a bond between atoms, so there are no bonds being broken, which would require significantly more energy to break than disrupting H-bonds. Topoisomerases on the other hand do need to catalyze breaks in the phosphate backbone in order to relieve tension from supercoiling. This is not to say that ATP is not consumed, just that bonds are not broken in the process as you are stating.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is perhaps not as simple as you may think, in part because there are many different helicases in the human body. There is also some passive activity of a helicase that does not require ATP.

It is not clear exactly whether ATP is just involved in the translocation of the helicase or the actual unwinding.

For a RecQ helicase in *E. coli*, one study found that "The determined tight mechanochemical coupling of 1.1 ± 0.2 ATP consumed per nucleotide traveled indicates an inchworm-type mechanism." For more information see [Sarlós et al. (2012)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3382518/).

Another study ([Donmez and Patel, 2008](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2435122/)) notes that "As compared with non-ring-shaped helicases such as PcrA (Dillingham et al, 2000) and UvrD (Tomko et al, 2007) that move on an average 1 nt for every ATP hydrolysed, the ring-shaped T7 helicase is three times more fuel efficient." This shows how there can be quite a bit of variation.

Bottom line - you can count on your fingers the number of nucleotides unwound by a helicase per ATP.